# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /uploads while unzipping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am unzipping my file that is already uploaded using carrierwave and I am running this code on localhost using console. File is already there in my uploads folder and I need to unzip it for reading the contents.

```
Zip::File.open(Rails.root.to_s + "/public" + self.submission.file_path.to_s) { |zip_file|
  puts zip_file.inspect
  zip_file.each { |file|
    file_path = File.join("solution", file.name)
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(Rails.root + "/public" + self.submission.file_path.to_s))
    zip_file.extract(file, file_path) unless File.exist?(file_path)
  }
}
```

and giving me the error

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /uploads
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `mkdir'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `each'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `mkdir_p'
    from /Users/Linux/Documents/rails/recruitment/app/models/candidate.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in unzip_solution'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib/zip/entry_set.rb:42:in `call'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib/zip/entry_set.rb:42:in `block in each'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib/zip/entry_set.rb:41:in `each'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib/zip/entry_set.rb:41:in `each'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib/zip/central_directory.rb:182:in `each'
    from /Users/Linux/Documents/rails/recruitment/app/models/candidate.rb:20:in `block in unzip_solution'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib/zip/file.rb:99:in `open'
    from /Users/Linux/Documents/rails/recruitment/app/models/candidate.rb:18:in `unzip_solution'
... 2 levels...
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Linux/Documents/rails/recruitment/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Linux/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Comment: what does `ls -l uploads` show ?

Comment: Please `puts File.join Rails.root, "public", self.submission.file_path.to_s` and show us the result of the above.

Comment: @niceman I have added chmod -R 777 to my uploads folder.You can see it in my previous comment. Bdw thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant permissions to access the required directory for the system root user

```
sudo chmod 777 -R your_project_directory_to_be_access
```

In your case you can use:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /your/project/public/
```

For security reasons, just keep in your mind:

`chmod 777` gives everybody read, write and execute rights which for most problems is definitively too much.